# Calling a Acumatica report using screen based soap api in java

Tags: java, soap, acumatica

I am using Java to get a *Acumatica* report using screen based *SOUP Web Services* *(code generated using `Apache CXF`)*. The report I am interested in is `Transactions for Periods` in Finance. I know how to pass commands to the web service to specify returned results, but I don't know how to pass parameters.

The parameters I want to pass are `fromPeriod`, `toPeriod`, `Ledger`, `fromAccount` and `toAccount`. Do I pass the parameters as filters or some other way? If as filters, how do I create the filter objects?

I can not find any examples in Java for calling *Acumatica* SOAP Web Services, so any help is much appreciated.

---

```
screen = service.getScreenSoap();
LoginResult lres = screen.login(username, password);

Content content = screen.getSchema();  
ArrayOfFilter filters = new ArrayOfFilter();

ArrayOfCommand commands = new ArrayOfCommand();

commands.getCommand().add(content.getReportResults().getHtmlContent());
ArrayOfArrayOfString result = screen.export(commands, filters, 0, true, true);
List<ArrayOfString> lines = result.getArrayOfString();
```

If I call the report without parameters I get the following errors:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: 
Server was unable to process request. --> PX.Data.PXViewDoesNotExitException: 
Error: The view Parameters doesn't exist.
```

I changed my code to match C# code in the answer:

```
              Content content = screen.getSchema();  
              ArrayOfFilter filters = new ArrayOfFilter();

              Value fromPeriod = new Value();
              fromPeriod.setLinkedCommand(content.getParameters().getFromPeriod());
              fromPeriod.setValue("06-2018");

              Value toPeriod = new Value();
              toPeriod.setLinkedCommand(content.getParameters().getToPeriod());
              toPeriod.setValue("06-2018");

              Value ledger = new Value();
              ledger.setLinkedCommand(content.getParameters().getLedger());
              ledger.setValue("ACTUAL");

              Value company = new Value();
              company.setLinkedCommand(content.getParameters().getCompany());
              company.setValue("PRODUCTS");

              Value branch = new Value();
              branch.setLinkedCommand(content.getParameters().getBranch());
              branch.setValue("PRODWHOLE");

              ArrayOfCommand commands = new ArrayOfCommand();
              commands.getCommand().add(content.getReportResults().getHtmlContent());
              commands.getCommand().add(fromPeriod);
              commands.getCommand().add(toPeriod);
              commands.getCommand().add(ledger);
              commands.getCommand().add(company);
              commands.getCommand().add(branch);

              ArrayOfArrayOfString result = screen.export(commands, filters, 0, true, true);
```

I now get a new error:

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at PX.Data.PXViewCollection.get_Item(String key)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper..ctor(SyExportContext context, Boolean submit)
   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.a(String A_0, Command[] A_1, Int32 A_2, Int32 A_3, Boolean A_4, Boolean A_5, Dictionary`2 A_6, OptimizedExportProviderBuilderForScreenBasedApi A_7, Boolean A_8, PXViewDescription[] A_9, ScreenInfo A_10, HashSet`1 A_11, Dictionary`2 A_12, SyExportContext A_13)
   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.ExportInternal(String screenId, Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 startRow, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError, PXGraph graph, Boolean bindGuids, Boolean mobile, Boolean isSelector, String forcePrimaryView, String bindContainer, Dictionary`2 sorts, String guidViewName, OptimizedExportProviderBuilderForScreenBasedApi buildOptimizedExportProviderDelegate, Func`3 serializationDelegate)
   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Export(String id, Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 startRow, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError, Boolean bindGuids, Boolean mobile, Boolean isSelector, String forcePrimaryView, PXGraph forceGraph, String bindContainer, Dictionary`2 sorts, String guidViewName, Boolean disableOptimizedExport)
   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Export(Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.mapException(JaxWsClientProxy.java:195) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.2.jar:3.3.2]
       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.export(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
       at com.appcomputing.be.acdata.acumatica.gl633000.GL633000.getReport(GL633000.java:89) [classes/:?]
       at com.appcomputing.be.acdata.acumatica.gl633000.GL633000.main(GL633000.java:115) [classes/:?]
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at PX.Data.PXViewCollection.get_Item(String key)
   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper..ctor(SyExportContext context, Boolean submit)
   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.a(String A_0, Command[] A_1, Int32 A_2, Int32 A_3, Boolean A_4, Boolean A_5, Dictionary`2 A_6, OptimizedExportProviderBuilderForScreenBasedApi A_7, Boolean A_8, PXViewDescription[] A_9, ScreenInfo A_10, HashSet`1 A_11, Dictionary`2 A_12, SyExportContext A_13)
   at PX.Api.ScreenUtils.ExportInternal(String screenId, Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 startRow, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError, PXGraph graph, Boolean bindGuids, Boolean mobile, Boolean isSelector, String forcePrimaryView, String bindContainer, Dictionary`2 sorts, String guidViewName, OptimizedExportProviderBuilderForScreenBasedApi buildOptimizedExportProviderDelegate, Func`3 serializationDelegate)
   at PX.Api.Services.ScreenService.Export(String id, Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 startRow, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError, Boolean bindGuids, Boolean mobile, Boolean isSelector, String forcePrimaryView, PXGraph forceGraph, String bindContainer, Dictionary`2 sorts, String guidViewName, Boolean disableOptimizedExport)
   at PX.Api.Soap.Screen.ScreenGate.Export(Command[] commands, Filter[] filters, Int32 topCount, Boolean includeHeaders, Boolean breakOnError)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I finally got the webservice to work after replacing the screen.export(...) with screen.submit(commands). But the result just has a long binary (non-text) string.

If anyone can help interpret this string (we need the data values in the report) that would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

This code example is in C# and it is for pdf file, but I think it may be useful. It is pretty much self explanatory:

```
//Getting the printable version of an invoice
//on the Invoice & Memo form (S0643000)
public static void GetPrintableInvoice()
{
    //Invoice data
    string docType = "Invoice";
    string invoiceNbr = "INV000045";
    using
    (
    //Connect to the web services and log in to Acumatica ERP
    Screen context = WebServiceConnector.InitializeWebService())
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the schema of the Invoice & Memo form (S0643000)
            SO643000Content invoiceFormSchema = context.SO643000GetSchema();
            //Specify the needed invoice and get a PDF version of it
            var commands = new Command[]
            {
                new Value
                {
                    Value = docType,
                    LinkedCommand = invoiceFormSchema.Parameters.DocumentType
                },
                new Value
                {
                    Value = invoiceNbr,
                    LinkedCommand = invoiceFormSchema.Parameters.ReferenceNumber
                },
                invoiceFormSchema.ReportResults.PdfContent
            };
            //Submit the commands to the form
            SO643000Content[] pdfInvoice = context.SO643000Submit(commands);
            //Save the result in a PDF file
            if (pdfInvoice != null && pdfInvoice.Length > 0)
            {
                File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format(@"Invoice_{0}.pdf", invoiceNbr),
                Convert.FromBase64String(pdfInvoice[0].ReportResults.PdfContent.Value));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //Log out from Acumatica ERP
            context.Logout();
        }
    }
}
```

So, in your case it should be something like that:

```
screen = service.getScreenSoap();
LoginResult lres = screen.login(username, password);

Content content = screen.getSchema();  
ArrayOfFilter filters = new ArrayOfFilter();

ArrayOfCommand commands = new ArrayOfCommand();

commands.getCommand().add(content.getValue("ParamValue",content.Parameters.fromPeriod));
commands.getCommand().add(content.getReportResults().getHtmlContent());
ArrayOfArrayOfString result = screen.export(commands, filters, 0, true, true);
List<ArrayOfString> lines = result.getArrayOfString();
```

Basically, you set parameter values the same way you set values for fields when you update a record

Comment: I changed my code to match the C# code above and now I get a new error posted above